# How to fragment cache "like" buttons ? (Rails 3.2, memcached)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My Rails app has `Post` and `Member` models. Within `posts/:id/show` contains a "like" button which Members can click, or "Unlike" if `@member` has already "liked" this `@post` already.

(This button will link to a post action that does some ajax and makes the "like" button change into a "unlike" button)

Whats the best practice for caching the button? (below code obviously doesn't cache the button html).

Should I add `:touch => true` to `member.rb`, and then make a cache key for the button e.g. `<% cache ['V1', @post, @member, 'like_button']` ? (seems redundant?)

**post.rb**

```
has_many :likes
```

**like.rb**

```
belongs_to :member
belongs_to :post
```

**member.rb**

```
has_many :likes
```

**posts/show.html.erb **

```
<% cache ['V1', @post, 'show'] do %>
  <h1>@post.title</h1>
  <div class="content">@post.content</div>
<% end %> 
  <%= render 'like_button', :post=> @post, :member => @member %>
```

** posts/_like_button.html.erb **

```
<% if member.liked_post?(post) %> 
  <%= link_to unlike_post_path(post), :method => :post, :remote => true, :class => 'btn' %>
<% else %> 
  <%= link_to like_post_path(post), :method => :post, :remote => true, :class => 'btn' %>  
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something along these lines:

```
<% cache ['V1', @post, @member.liked_post?(@post), 'show'] do %>
  <h1>@post.title</h1>
  <div class="content">@post.content</div>
  <%= render 'like_button', :post=> @post, :member => @member %> 
<% end %>
```

This gives your 2 different cached versions of the fragment - one each for the 'liked' and 'not liked' states.  This is better than 1 version per user.

YOu run the risk here of someone adding code to the **like_button** partial that uses more of the @member parameter, and that isn't part of the cache key, so you'll get incorrect results.

For this case, I'd change the **like_button** partial to take the same parameter as the cache call - **@member.liked_post(@post)** -- to make it clear that this is the only value used inside the partial code.

```
<%= render 'like_button', :post=> @post, :liked => @member.liked(@post) %>
```

With the new partial:

```
<% if liked %> 
  <%= link_to unlike_post_path(post), :method => :post, :remote => true, :class => 'btn' %>
<% else %> 
  <%= link_to like_post_path(post), :method => :post, :remote => true, :class => 'btn' %>  
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi Tom thanks for your comment. I'm interested in "best practice" -- it seems like it would be a Good Idea to cache the like_button partial separately from the rest of the page ? How can I still cache the button when post is not yet liked by member? (or is the cost small enough?)

Comment: In your example the `like` button would be a `:post` method -- is this because its easier to cache, as opposed to using `:get`...?

Comment: The 'like' button in my example is exactly the same as in your code - the only difference in the file is the first line of the file.

In my example, you'll have 2 cached versions of the code for each post, one for people who have liked the post, and one for people who have not liked it.

The Best Practice is to cache as much as possible, without making the system too hard to maintain.  This is why I moved the @member.liked? call to outside the partial, to make it clear that this value - true or false - is the only thing that makes this partial behave differently.

Comment: There is overhead for retrieving cached fragments, so its good to reduce the number of memcache calls you need to make to build the page

Comment: Tom, I am running into this problem now and wanted clarification on your last point. If I have a list of 20 programs on a page that a User could both Like or Follow (for lack of better description). Is that going to be too many memcache calls?

Comment: It can be - 20 memcache calls could be too many.  There is a gem available that batches up memcache calls: https://github.com/n8/multi_fetch_fragments

This gem performs a single memcache call to get the set of data, and then generates the missing fragments (if there are any missing), and then saves the missing pieces.  So a max of 2 memcache calls.

I've used this with some success in my own projects